# How to fix 1364 field doesn't have a default value in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I insert query in database I get a problem like:

> `#`1364 'user_email' field doesn't have a default value .

We don't have STRICT mode for disable in godaddy sharing server. So, can anyone please suggest an alternative.

MySQL query below

```
INSERT INTO users_register(`user_type`,`user_fullname`,`user_password`,`user_mobileno`,`user_district`,`user_area`,`user_pincode`,`user_get`,`created_by`,`created_date`) VALUES('user','test' , '8ec3e41' , '9123333333' , '1' , '128' , '128' , '' , '' , '2016-11-12 16:28:53')
```

Comment: If you have assign user_mail  not null but without default value  when  you try to insert a row without user_mail  .. the  db raise this error .. . I fyou want insert rows without user_email .. try remove not null for this column

Comment: EDIT: added formatting, improved English.

Answer (score 0):

In your request you didn't mention 'user_email as field,

```
INSERT INTO users_register(`user_type`,`user_fullname`,'user_email
```